# How to create javascript function lookup object?

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to create a function lookup in Javascript essentially mapping a data type to a function that does something for that data type. Right now I have something similar to:

```
var Namespace = Namespace || {};
Namespace.MyObj = function () {
    var stringFunc = function(someData) {
        //Do some string stuff with someData
    };

    var intFunc = function(someData) {
        //Do some int stuff with someData
    };

    var myLookUp = {
        'string': stringFunc,
        'int' : intFunc
    };

    return {
         PublicMethod: function (dataType, someData) {
             myLookUp[dataType](someData);
         }
    };
} ();
```

When I invoke `Namespace.MyObj.PublicMethod(dataType, someData)` I get an error that myLookUp is not defined. I'm assuming I'm not going about setting up the function lookup object correctly, but not sure how to do so. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You're calling it like `var foo = new Namespace.MyObj(); foo.PublicMethod();` right?

Comment: No I'm calling it as Namespace.MyObj.PublicMethod(dataType, someData); but after I fixed my declaration that works :)

Comment: That can't possibly work; you must mean `Namespace.MyObj().PublicMethod(dataType, someData);`.

Comment: I don't know if makes a difference that MyObj is a function?? I was attempting to follow the pattern in this blog entry:
http://yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/
But I do call it as Namespace.MyObj.PublicMethod();

Comment: It looks like your question omitted the `()` at the very end, which immediately invokes the anonymous function.

Comment: @Matt Ball Thanks for the reference post: http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

Comment: No problem; I deleted my answer since it was for a totally different question. You're not implementing your own class, just applying the module pattern.

Comment: @Matt Ball Good catch, I over looked that. Updated my example code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem might simply be incorrect case

```
myLookup[dataType](someData);
```

should be (notice the capital U)

```
myLookUp[dataType](someData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just looked at my post after I wrote it up, stupid oversight, I'm declaring the properties as strings, instead of just properties.

```
....
var myLookUp = {
    string: stringFunc,
    int: intFunc
};
....
```

Fixes the issue.

Some additional follow up, in my actual code dataType is the result of a jQuery select. Don't know why or if this would be browser dependant (I'm using FireFox), but using double quotes around the property definition works, single quotes does not, and no quotes works as well. :-\

Comment: The problem isn't quoting the `myLookUp` properties - there's nothing wrong with that. [Yisroel found the actual problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104757/how-to-create-javascript-function-lookup-object/6104790#6104790).

Comment: Perhaps if the method is called with datatype passed without quotes?

Comment: @Yisroel nope. In this case there is **zero** difference between quoting the keys, and not quoting them.